# Spring Security with jdbcAuthentication throws There is no PasswordEncoder mapped for the id "null"

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa, spring-jdbc

I am currently learning SpringSecurity with spring boot using `h2` database.

I am using jdbcAuthentication for authentication when I try to login through the username and password it throws:

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: There is no PasswordEncoder mapped for the id "null"`

I am using password encoder as: 
    `PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder()`.

Here is the error log

```
 .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.6.RELEASE)

2020-04-28 01:55:46.232  INFO 22525 --- [           main] c.s.s.SpringSecurityJdbcApplication      : Starting SpringSecurityJdbcApplication on harsh with PID 22525 (/home/harsh/rapid/chatak-pg-microservices/spring-security-jdbc/target/classes started by harsh in /home/harsh/rapid/chatak-pg-microservices/spring-security-jdbc)
2020-04-28 01:55:46.235  INFO 22525 --- [           main] c.s.s.SpringSecurityJdbcApplication      : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-04-28 01:55:46.943  INFO 22525 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JDBC repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2020-04-28 01:55:46.966  INFO 22525 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 16ms. Found 0 JDBC repository interfaces.
2020-04-28 01:55:47.467  INFO 22525 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2020-04-28 01:55:47.475  INFO 22525 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-04-28 01:55:47.475  INFO 22525 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.33]
2020-04-28 01:55:47.527  INFO 22525 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-04-28 01:55:47.527  INFO 22525 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1242 ms
2020-04-28 01:55:47.686  INFO 22525 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-04-28 01:55:47.784  INFO 22525 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2020-04-28 01:55:47.993  INFO 22525 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: any request, [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@46678e49, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@3fae596, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@1d25c1c, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@27b000f7, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@67e28be3, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@6f3f0fae, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter@4a5905d9, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter@748e9b20, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@42fcc7e6, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@73017a80, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@2063c53e, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@5bca7664, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@333cb916, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@1b29d52b]
2020-04-28 01:55:48.147  INFO 22525 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-04-28 01:55:48.533  INFO 22525 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2020-04-28 01:55:48.536  INFO 22525 --- [           main] c.s.s.SpringSecurityJdbcApplication      : Started SpringSecurityJdbcApplication in 2.688 seconds (JVM running for 3.258)
2020-04-28 01:55:51.231  INFO 22525 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-04-28 01:55:51.231  INFO 22525 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-04-28 01:55:51.240  INFO 22525 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 9 ms
2020-04-28 01:55:57.071 ERROR 22525 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: There is no PasswordEncoder mapped for the id "null"
    at org.springframework.security.crypto.password.DelegatingPasswordEncoder$UnmappedIdPasswordEncoder.matches(DelegatingPasswordEncoder.java:250) ~[spring-security-core-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
```

Here is my SpringSecurity class

> SpringSecurity.java

Security configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpringSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/admin").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .antMatchers("/user").hasAnyRole("ADMIN","USER")
        .antMatchers("/home").permitAll()
        .and()
        .formLogin();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication()
        .dataSource(dataSource)
        .passwordEncoder(getPassword()); 
    }

    public PasswordEncoder getPassword() {
        //actually do nothing 
        return PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
    }

}
```

> HomeController.java

```
@RestController
public class HomeController {

    @GetMapping("/home")
    public String home() {
        return ("<h1>Welome to Spring Security</h1>");
    }

    @GetMapping("/admin")
    public String admin() {
        return ("<h1>Welome ADMIN user to Spring Security</h1>");
    }

    @GetMapping("/user")
    public String user() {
        return ("<h1>Welome USER user to Spring Security</h1>");
    }
}
```

> application.properties

```
spring.datasource.continue-on-error=true
spring.datasource.initialize=true
spring.datasource.separator=;
spring.datasource.sql-script-encoding=UTF-8
```

> data.sql

```
insert into users (username,password,enabled) values ('user','user',true);
insert into users (username,password,enabled) values ('sadmin','admin',true);
insert into authorities(username,authority) values ('user','ROLE_USER');
insert into authorities(username,authority) values ('sadmin','ROLE_ADMIN');
```

> schema.sql

```
drop table users;
drop table authorities;
drop index ix_auth_username;

create table users(
    username varchar_ignorecase(50) not null primary key,
    password varchar_ignorecase(50) not null,
    enabled boolean not null
);

create table authorities (
    username varchar_ignorecase(50) not null,
    authority varchar_ignorecase(50) not null,
    constraint fk_authorities_users foreign key(username) references users(username)
);
create unique index ix_auth_username on authorities (username,authority);
```

Here is the attached screenshot of the project:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be sure that your password encoder really do nothing, you could use:

```java
@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() { 
    return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance(); 
}
```

It is just for educational reason.
Do not use it at real project.

Answer (score 2):

You should put @Bean:

```
@Bean
public PasswordEncoder getPassword() {
        return PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
}
```

Also, personnaly I use BCrypt and I set it on a authentication provider:

```
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
    auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
}

@Bean
PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
@Bean
DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider(){
    DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    daoAuthenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    daoAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(YourUserDetailsService);

    return daoAuthenticationProvider;
}
```

Comment: There are two things putting @Bean as suggested doesn't work with getPassword method 2nd is when using authenticationProvider as you have suggested what is the actually YourUserDetailsService?

Comment: this service is used to retreive user in database. Check this link for more information:
[https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-authentication-with-a-database](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-authentication-with-a-database)